# Return an array of single element from page.click() callback

Tags: puppeteer

Here is from the [document](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.9.0&show=api-pageclickselector-options) for `page.click()` for `Puppeteer`:

```
 const [response] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(waitOptions),
  page.click(selector, clickOptions),
]);
```

Since there is only one return value `response`, I don't quite understand why it was not as below:

```
 const response = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(waitOptions),
  page.click(selector, clickOptions),
]);
```

Would someone shed light on this declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has more to do with how [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Description) works than with puppeteer.

> **Promise.all**: [...] the returned promise is fulfilled with an array containing all the
>   values of the iterable passed as argument (also non-promise values).

That means `await Promise.all(...)` returns an array containing the results of both Promises. Now let's have a look at what both Promises fulfill to:

- [`page.waitForNavigation(waitOptions)`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.9.0&show=api-pagewaitfornavigationoptions): Promise which resolves to the main resource response.
- [`page.click(selector, clickOptions)`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.9.0&show=api-pageclickselector-options): Promise which resolves to undefined (returns no value).

So `await Promise.all([ ... ])` will result in an array with the first value being the main resource response and the second value being undefined.

Thanks to [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) we can write this as:

```js
const [response, valueWhichWillBeUndefined] = await Promise.all([ ... ]);
```

And as we are not interested in the second value, we can just leave that variable out (as we know it will be undefined) resulting in:

```js
const [response] = await Promise.all([ ... ]);
```

Comment: `Thomas Dondorf`, you are right and it is how `Promise.all` is defined. let me re-phrase my question, is it right to do `const response = Promise.all(promise1, promise2)` if I only care about return of `promise1`? It would be cleaner than array with single element. Thanks.

Comment: Based on my test, single variable of `response` won't cause error and it returns an array of `object`. It is `undefined` if rejected.

Comment: If you write `const response = Promise.all([...])`, response will be an array. So this works but then you have to write reponse[0] to access the value you want. If you write `const [response] = ...`, response will be assigned to the first value of the array (check out the link about destructuring assignment in my answer).